# jCarousel incorrectly offsetting slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

My jCarousel appears to be clipping off the side of each slide when paginating by incorrectly setting the left-side position of the active slide.

I looked at the position properties the plugin was applying to the current slide and it seems that it is offsetting the slide by an extra 100 pixels per left pagination (100 * n clicks..) for some reason. I have all my widths and heights defined as the documentation outlines, along with a fallback dimension.

Here's an example of the problem:

[image]

The top of the picture displays a slide with 6 items in it, displaying correctly when we're initialized to the first slide.

The bottom picture shows the incorrect offset after paginating to the next slide.

Also note, oddly, this only happens in Chrome. Firefox and IE seem to be fine.

Comment: can you add your code or set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)